# Are there any ancient Jewish dances?

Tags: minhag, history, dance

From what I've seen most (orthodox) Jewish dancing consists of people running or walking in a circle, sometimes with exciting variations such as foot stomping. Are there any records of ancient (pre-hassidic) dances and do any communities practice them?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I was referring to the mitzvah tanz or the mezinka

Comment: If there are any they would probably be related to Tu Be'Av (the 15th of Av).

Comment: Tu Be'av....in that the women would dance in the fields.

Comment: Waving the Lulav?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about jewish culture; not Judaism.

Comment: Check out "Dabke" which according to wikipedia is an old Phoenician dance and is notorious for its foot stomping. this style was adopted by the indigenous Arab population and was later adopted by the Israeli people. However, it is possible that the Israelites during the first temple period were influenced by their neighboring Phoenician culture and were familiar with Dabke... see Yechezkel 25:6.

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna in Sukkah (5:4) describes the dancing in the Bet Hamikdash during the *Simchat Bet haSho'eva*. It is described as juggling torches of fire.

> חֲסִידִים  וְאַנְשֵׁי מַעֲשֶׂה הָיוּ מְרַקְּדִים לִפְנֵיהֶם  בַּאֲבוּקוֹת שֶׁל אוֹר שֶׁבִּידֵיהֶן, וְאוֹמְרִים לִפְנֵיהֶן דִּבְרֵי שִׁירוֹת וְתִשְׁבָּחוֹת

The Gemara (Sukkah 53a) also mentions bowing down - Kida - which looked a lot like push-ups.

> תניא אמרו עליו על רבן שמעון בן גמליאל כשהיה שמח שמחת בית השואבה היה **נוטל שמנה אבוקות של אור וזורק אחת ונוטל אחת ואין נוגעות זו בזו** וכשהוא משתחוה **נועץ שני גודליו בארץ ושוחה ונושק את הרצפה** וזוקף ואין כל בריה יכולה לעשות כן וזו היא קידה ‏

Comment: do you know what qida looks like? how do you know it "looked a lot like push-ups"? is being mishtahwo upon the floor and shoho kissing it, which is called qidho, dancing? what do any of these words mean?